# Joins with Keycloak java admin client

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I m trying to understand the admin client api of Keycloak, especially around joins.

There is this post that adresses a similar need for getting users per role.

[Keycloak - Get all Users mapped to roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371943/keycloak-get-all-users-mapped-to-roles)

How would we do this with the admin client?

Because for now I am retrieving all users and checking if the roles match:

```
List<UserRepresentation> userRepresentations = keycloak.realm(realm).users().search("", 0, 1000); //get all users :(
        for (UserRepresentation userRepresentation : userRepresentations ) {
            List<String> userRoles = userRepresentation.getRealmRoles();

            if(userRoles != null && !Collections.disjoint(userRoles, roles)){
                result.add(KeycloakUserTransformer.userRepresentationToSimpleUserDTO(userRepresentation));
            }
        }
```

And the thing is, userRoles list is always empty :S. But actually, we have ~2500 users in keycloak users.

EDIT: 
I am using the keycloak admin client v.2.0. I guess the newer versions support this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With latest admin client you can easily get

```
RoleResource roleResource = keycloak.realm("realm_name").roles().get("role_name");  
    Set<UserRepresentation> users = roleResource.getRoleUserMembers();
```

Comment: Careful, this only gives u the direct assigned user to this role, not the effective ones.
I prefer to use groups for querys of users sets.