# unreliable results from Keycloak Admin REST API /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}/users

Tags: keycloak-rest-api

I get unreliable results from Keycloak Admin REST API
`/{realm}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}/users` when users are in the hundreds.

Using a simple for loop with the keycloak-admin-client lib in java, I get a different results count from one run to another.
For example, I get a different result before and after clicking 'synchronise all users' on one of the
LDAP users federations...

Any idea why ?

So I went back to exporting via pgsql

```
SELECT username, first_name, last_name, email, cli.client_id, kr.name, r.name as realm_name, ua.value
                FROM keycloak_role kr
                JOIN user_role_mapping rm ON kr.id = rm.role_id
                JOIN user_entity ue ON rm.user_id = ue.id
                JOIN client cli ON cli.id = kr.client
                JOIN realm r ON kr.realm_id=r.id
                LEFT JOIN user_attribute ua ON ue.id = ua.user_id and ua.name='LDAP_ENTRY_DN'
                WHERE kr.name IN ('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN') and r.name=$1
                and cli.client_id IN (<list of clients>) order by username
```

(this question [Keycloak - Get all Users mapped to roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371943/keycloak-get-all-users-mapped-to-roles) didn't mention this problem though)